# Trouble with install & configuring CI/CD

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We have fully configured and working perfect corporate gitlab server. And now i try to use CI/CD on it.
1. Our sysadmin gave me a virtual server on corporate network with ubuntu 20.04 installed.
2. I read (and understand) the docs about installing and configuring gitlab runner, docker engine, docker machine, docker hub, virtualbox software.
3. I installed Gitlab Runner on virtual server.
4. I register runner with "shell" type
5. Create a project with this **.gitlab-ci.yml** file:

```
test_variable:
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker run --rm hello-world
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo $CI_JOB_STAGE
    - ls -la
    - tree
```

6. I start the CI / CD pipeline and make sure that everything works fine.
   Then I try to run this in docker:
7. Install the docker engine.
8. Install the docker machine (forked version from gitlab) (I try both version)
9. I create a new machine. Everything  work perfectly.
   Now I'm testing it locally - run a docker, run new docker machine, create new machine and run it again - everything works fine.
10. I register a new runner, with type "docker".
11. And this new runner does not work with the same **.gitlab-ci.yml** file:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.2.0 (11.2.0)
   on docker-runner zQ6fuswY
 Using Docker executor with image ubuntu ...
 Pulling docker image gitlab-runner-helper:11.2.0 ...
 ERROR: Failed to create container volume for /var/builds/work/rbushnyakov 
  Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gitlab-runner-helper, 
  repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested 
  access to the resource is denied (executor_docker.go:166:1s)
 ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gitlab-runner-helper,
  repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the 
  resource is denied (executor_docker.go:166:1s)
```

What am I doing wrong and what is my mistake?

My **/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml**

```
  [[runners]]
    name = "simple-runner"
    url = "https://git.our.corporate.site/"
    token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    executor = "shell"
    shell = "bash"
    builds_dir = "/var/builds/work/"
    cache_dir = "/var/builds/cache/"
    [runners.cache]
  [[runners]]
    name = "docker-runner"
    url = "https://git.our.corporate.site/"
    token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    executor = "docker"
    builds_dir = "/var/builds/work/"
    cache_dir = "/var/builds/cache/"
    [runners.docker]
      tls_cert_path = "/root/.docker/machine/machines/default"
      tls_verify = false
      image = "ubuntu"
      privileged = true
      disable_cache = false
      volumes = ["/var/builds/cache"]
      shm_size = 0
    [runners.cache]
```

Thank you for your attention, I really hope for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Thanks [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4773#note_264299322) solution.
The problem is - the quote:

> ...
> the reason this happens is that we use Git revision in the
> gitlab-runner --version output to pull the correct helper image, and
> the official GitLab Runner binaries output a commit SHA and not the
> tag:
> ...

So, during the first load, the docker engine wants to get certain tags, but these tags are missing.
So I downloaded the gitlab-runner-helper version 11.2.0 with a different tag that works and
renamed it locally.

Follow [link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4773#note_264299322) and read carefully. It is described in more detail there.

Comment: Right, Look carefully at the output error.  My mistake was old gitlab-runner that tried to get gitlab-runner-helper old version.